# Geometry: Why is the distance AP $2\sin(\pi/4-\theta/2)$?

Tags: geometry, circles

The graph shows a hemicircle (radius 1). Taylor (author of Classical Mechanics) says the length AP is

$$2\sin(\pi/4-\theta/2).$$

His explanation is "drop a perpendicular from the center to the line AP," which I don't understand.

[image]

Comment: Is the radius given?

Comment: Who is Taylor? Do you mean a book by author of the same name?

Comment: Radius 1. And yes, Taylor wrote Classical Mechanics. Edited to clarify both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

If $O$ is the center of the circle, then $\angle AOP = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$.

$OA = OP$ so if we drop a perpendicular from $O$ to $AP$, it will divide $\angle AOP$ and $AP$ into half. Say the perpendicular from $O$ to $AP$ meets $AP$ at $H$ then

$\angle HOP =  \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\theta}{2} , \ $ So $HP = \frac{AP}{2} = OP \sin (\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\theta}{2})$

$ \therefore AP = 2 OP \sin (\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\theta}{2})$

and $AP = 2 \sin (\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\theta}{2}) \ $ only if the semicircle has unit radius.

Comment: Thanks, Math Lover. Super clear. :)

Comment: You are welcome!